# Can an app support multiple APNS keys? -> require p12 and p8 for the same app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, intercom

our app needs to receive push notifications from multiple sources.  (our own server, and also intercom)

To set up our own server we were required to provide p12

Now a new requirement to allow intercom to push to our app ->  but intercom demands a p8

Q) can I just create a new key and generate the required p8 file for intercom without disrupting the existing push p12?  We can have both keys active at the same time for the same app?

What are my options?

thanks

Comment: Yes. The keys identify your development team to APNS.  They aren't anything to do with your app directly.  As long as the certificate is valid and associated with the same team as the app you are good.